# R Leaflet not mapping polylines to datarame

Tags: r, leaflet

I use Leaflet with R quite frequently, but I've not used addPolylines before.

I have a series of lines with origin and destination locations that I'm attempting to plot on a map, and I'm noticing some weird behaviour:

- [Polylines and markers mapped to the same dataframe are not appearing in the same location](https://i.gyazo.com/c68d21dde35c0d0e52f5dd99182d887a.png).
- Labels are not mapping at all to the dataframe, instead only returning the values in the last row for all lines.
- Line weight mapping is not working.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here - any help would be appreciated. I've included a reproducible example below.

```
dummy <- data.frame(
    Line_name = c("line1", "line2", "line3"),
    origin_lng = c(145.1234, 147.223, 153.225),
    origin_lat = c(-17, -19.4, -27.6),
    Destination_lng = c(147.223, 153.225, 156.1123),
    Destination_lat = c(-19.4, -27.6, -30.5),
    Line_weight = c(1, 2, 5)
  )
  
  leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles(provider = providers$Esri.WorldImagery) %>%
    setView(lng = 146.612020, lat = -21.628836, zoom = 5) %>%
    addMarkers(lng = dummy$origin_lng, lat = dummy$origin_lat, label = "origins") %>%
    addPolylines(
      lng = c(dummy$origin_lng, dummy$Destination_lng),
      lat = c(dummy$Origin_lat, dummy$Destination_lat),
      weight = dummy$Line_weight,
      label = paste0(
        "Line name: ", dummy$Line_name, "<br>",
        "Origin coords: ", dummy$origin_lng, " ", dummy$origin_lat, "<br>",
        "Destination coords: ", dummy$Destination_lng, " ", dummy$Destination_lat
      ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group the lines. You used the columns of `dummy` as independent vectors but sent no groups. Leaflet doesn't 'know' which labels go with which line segments. Additionally, you did get a popup, but you have to hover. (You only had one, as well.)

So, in short—grouping the data... There is probably an easier way of doing this, but this works. I pivoted longer to going the lat/long. Then I pivoted wider. Essentially, I needed the longs in a column and the lats in a column.

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

dum2 <- dummy %>% pivot_longer(cols = names(.)[2:5], names_to = c("ft", "val"), 
                       names_sep = "_", values_to = "lng_lat") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("Line_name", "ft", "Line_weight"),
                          names_from = "val", values_from = "lng_lat")
```

Then I separated the call for `addPolyLines`. You need one call for each group.

```
mp <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$Esri.WorldImagery) %>%
  setView(lng = 146.612020, lat = -21.628836, zoom = 5) %>%
  addMarkers(lng = dummy$origin_lng, lat = dummy$origin_lat, label = "origins")

map(dummy$Line_name,
    function(group){
      mp <<- addPolylines(
        mp,
        data = dum2[dum2$Line_name == group, ],
        lng = ~lng,
        lat = ~lat,
        weight = ~Line_weight,
        labelOptions = list(noHide = T, sticky = T, permanent = T),
        label = paste0(
          "Line name: ", group, "<br>",
          "Origin coords: ", dummy[dummy$Line_name == group, ]$origin_lng, 
          " ", dummy[dummy$Line_name == group, ]$origin_lat, "<br>",
          "Destination coords: ", dummy[dummy$Line_name == group, ]$Destination_lng, 
          " ", dummy[dummy$Line_name == group, ]$Destination_lat) %>% 
          lapply(htmltools::HTML))
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks!